# Equivalent to ddply(...,transform,...) in data.table

Tags: r, transform, data.table, plyr

I have the following code using `ddply` from plyr package:

```
ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),transform,freq=length(cyl))
```

The data.table version of this is :

```
DT<-data.table(mtcars)

DT[,freq:=.N,by=cyl]
```

How can I extend this when I have more than one function like the one below?

Now, I want to perform more than one function on `ddply` and `data.table`:

```
ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),transform,freq=length(cyl),sum=sum(mpg))

DT[,list(freq=.N,sum=sum(mpg)),by=cyl]
```

But, `data.table` gives me only three columns cyl,freq, and sum. Well, I can do like this:

```
DT[,list(freq=.N,sum=sum(mpg),mpg,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb),by=cyl]
```

But, I have large number of variables in my read data and I want all of them to be there as in `ddply(...transform....)`. Is there shortcut in `data.table` just like doing `:=` when we have only one function (as above) or something like this `paste(names(mtcars),collapse=",")` within `data.table`? 
Note: I also have a large number of function to run. So, I can't repeat `=:` a number of times (but I would prefer this if `lapply` can be applied here).

Comment: If you just want to add columns, I believe the best equivalent to `ddply` syntax is something like ``DT[,`:=`(freq = .N, sum = sum(mpg))]``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use backquoted `:=` like this...

```
DT[ , `:=`( freq = .N , sum = sum(mpg) ) , by=cyl ]
head( DT , 3 )
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb freq   sum
#1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    7 138.2
#2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    7 138.2
#3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   11 293.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Also useful in some situations:

```
newvars <- c("freq","sum")
DT[, `:=`(eval(newvars), list(.N,sum(mpg)))]
```

Comment: you might also consider 'get' or 'mget' instead of 'eval' for this, e.g. (untested) ``DT[, `:=`(mget(newvars), list(.N,sum(mpg)))]``