# R How to add multiple columns (:=) to data.table based on results of rollapplyr in .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to add some columns to a large data.table that are based on rolling calculations split by a unique identifier.

Based on [Equivalent to ddply(...,transform,...) in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569145/transform-of-ddply-like-in-data-table) I have generated this statement:

```
alldefaults[,`:=`(.SD[,list(obsPaymentDownMax24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,max,partial=TRUE) 
                       ,obsPaymentDownAvg24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,mean,partial=TRUE)
                       ,obsPaymentDownMax12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,max,partial=TRUE)
                       ,obsPaymentDownAvg12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,mean,partial=TRUE))]),by=OriginalApplicationID]
```

It produces an error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(alldefaults, , `:=`(.SD[, list(obsPaymentDownMax24m = rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,  : 
  In `:=`(col1=val1, col2=val2, ...) form, all arguments must be named.
```

When I run this without the function `:=` named it work well but is a new dataset and then joining it back on would be required.

Inserting the assignment within the .SD

```
alldefaults[,.SD[,`:=`(list(obsPaymentDownMax24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,max,partial=TRUE) 
                        ,obsPaymentDownAvg24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,mean,partial=TRUE)
                        ,obsPaymentDownMax12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,max,partial=TRUE)
                        ,obsPaymentDownAvg12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,mean,partial=TRUE)))],by=OriginalApplicationID]
```

Produces this error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(.SD, , `:=`(list(obsPaymentDownMax24m = rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,  : 
  .SD is locked. Using := in .SD's j is reserved for possible future use; a tortuously flexible way to modify by group. Use := in j directly to modify by group by reference.
```

Is there a trick to making this update work that I've missed?

PS - Not sure if this a hefty enough question to require a reproducible example as it seems primarily syntax oriented and is hopefully easy to point out what the statement ought to be. Also if anyone has recommendations for making this faster again, I'd be very appreciative!

Comment: -1. How about trying for a *minimal* example then. If you see this behavior with just one rollapplyr, for example, you do not need to show four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing (guessing, because the question is not well formed, which is probably why you got downvoted) you want to do this:

```
alldefaults[,`:=`(obsPaymentDownMax24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,max,partial=TRUE) 
                 ,obsPaymentDownAvg24m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,24,mean,partial=TRUE)
                 ,obsPaymentDownMax12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,max,partial=TRUE)
                 ,obsPaymentDownAvg12m=rollapplyr(obsPaymentsDown,12,mean,partial=TRUE)),by=OriginalApplicationID]
```